# ExtensionMethod ThrowIf Invert Func<T,bool>

Tags: c#, extension-methods, func

I have written an extension method which throws an Exception if a boolean function evaluates to true/false for a given type T.

```
    public static void ThrowIf<T>(this T source, Func<T,bool> func, string name, bool invert = false)
    {
        if (func.Invoke(source) != invert)
            throw new ArgumentException(func.Method.Name + " check failed, inverted:" + invert, name);
    }
```

which I am using in following fashion

```
name.ThrowIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty, "name");
path.ThrowIf(File.Exists, "path", true);
```

Is there a neater solution to include the inverting functionality than passing the flag in my ThrowIf or creating a ThrowIfNot?

Comment: If you don’t pass some information that it should be inverted, and you don’t have some other name to signalize that behavior, how should this possibly work?

Comment: Extension methods that apply to all types? Yuck. Throwing `ArgumentException` rather than `ArgumentNullException` when the input is `null`? Yuck. Checking `File.Exists` instead of just opening, introducing race conditions? Yuck. Think very carefully about not just how to improve this method, but also whether you want this method at all.

Comment: @hvd yes, valid point, I was just posting simple examples. I am actually not using them that way.

Comment: @poke something like that for example
    name.ThrowIf(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s), "name");
I guess this is clean enough for me

Comment: If that’s okay with you, then doesn’t that already work? What are you having problems with?

Comment: If I use an anonymous method I don't have a proper name which I am printing with func.Method.Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that clearly another method would be more meaningful (*as you've already said in your question...*):

```
name.ThrowIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty, "name");
path.ThrowIfNot(File.Exists, "path");
```

...and you could just make your `ThrowIf` with the invert `true`/`false` parameter *private*:

```
private static void ThrowIf<T>(this T source, Func<T,bool> func, string name, bool invert)
{
    if (func.Invoke(source) != invert)
        throw new ArgumentException(func.Method.Name + " check failed, inverted:" + invert, name);
}

public static void ThrowIf<T>(this T source, Func<T, bool> func, string name) 
       => ThrowIf<T>(source, func, name, false);
public static void ThrowIfNot<T>(this T source, Func<T, bool> func, string name) 
       => ThrowIf<T>(source, func, name, true);
```

BTW, maybe it's better that you refactor everything to use [*code contracts*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) if you're looking for implementing parameter validation:

```
public void SomeMethod(string someParameter)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(someParameter));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint to code contracts. I forgot about them.